# Php encrypt url

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, url, encryption

i need your help , i am using codeigniter php to do url encryption,

i use default codeigniter encryption class , without changing the configuration,

but when i encrypt the url show me error

"Object Not found , the request url was not found on this server"

the way i encrypt the url

```
$e_email_app = $this->encryption->encrypt($email_app);
$e_email_app = urlencode($e_email_app);
$newurl = base_url()."job_applicant/fill_data/".$e_email_app;
```

i already enable apache mod_rewrite on http.conf , i am using virtual host like this

```
<VirtualHost *:83>
    ServerAdmin 192.168.77.204:83
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/Vacancy/public"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/Vacancy/public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes execCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow From All
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

and my .htacess is

RewriteEngine on

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]
```

What should i do ? change the encryption algorithm ?
Please help..

@George Sazanovich : Thx for your advise , but no problem with codeigniter, because sometimes it fail sometimes it success , and i had setup the encryption key

example success :
http://192.168.77.204:83/job_applicant/fill_data/5325d49c38a855e9f64a0cf0c0c9ae84ff8bb0f38a36253ef08f5359281e1208d0a6550a276e6ca89be70bb5b782000aeded81d3375106225f59b15c8895d3bcFHj8y8XdZtAXOXH1LAXHir5qkLjOopna1WKdM5eElInp8Ga7nNaD5Zvm607lL%2Bid

example fail :
http://192.168.77.204:83/job_applicant/fill_data/321ad7709eb97a6a5d72d6a53b40a263a8d676ad8a1cdee72c5440a1cccb94c97c4bc50b8f7aee909a3d65d75e61a86cff87fba66e0a8adb5ec8529ee4a1c482bh9rV7%2FGubenEFC1xXxePVwx%2FAn2eR6uXUbQfhcPREQ%3D

maybe the apache url configuration ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems You're trying to use reserved name `CI_Controller`

```
$newurl = base_url()."controller/method/".$e_email_app;
```

or this was edited for question and You have a real name for controller and method? Also, please, check is encryption was success:

```
$email_app = "test string";
$newurl = base_url("controller/method/".urlencode($this->encryption->encode($email_app)));
$decoded = $this->encryption->decode(urldecode($newurl));
echo $decoded; // must be "test string" after Your base_url()
```

And one more: for using encryption library You **must** set encyption key at config file (`application/config/config.php` -> `$config['encryption_key']`).

If everything is ok there's only one reason to break You script: apache/CodeIgniter trims part of Your URL. Easiest way to check it - view what's recieved at controller:

```
 /* controller (for example mymail) defenition here */
 // here's your http://domain.com/mymail/mycheck/
 public function mycheck($param){
   var_dump($param);
 }
```

Also, `base_url()` accepts param, so

`base_url().'test/param';` will equal 
`base_url('test/param');`

**EDIT**

I've checked You string and it seems to be illegal to post "`%2F`" at GET. So problem in illegal characters at Your encoded string (You can try use only %2F as Your encoded string and it'll crush app).

**UPDATE**

%2F will be urldecoded as `/` with browser (such as %20 (whitespace). So Browser thinks Your request is `/controller/method/_encoded_string_/_part_after_%2F_`

Comment: validate the encryption and decrypt again in CI work well , but when place the encryption string to url its the problem

Comment: @StefenWiranata check string and `$config['permitted_uri_chars']` in `application/config/config.php`, maybe You're trying to post illegal symbols?